# SDK Manager cant download the APIs and Addons?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, eclipse-adt

Today I set in my new working Environment and I have to install eclipse. I downloaded the `ADT`, and when I tried to download eclipse Plug-Ins from the link `http://` it did not work because of Connection issues. I coped this Problem by downloading the Plug-Ins as a zip file and I added it.

Now, when I open eclipse and click on the SDK Manager to download the new APIs and the other stuff, I receive the below posted Screen shot. Is there any other way to install it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are connecting to the internet through a firewall or proxy server. check this out and it should work. Also when you try to open the SDK manager try to run it as an administrator. because some folders are somehow protected, and when the SDK tries to write into it, it faces acess problems. So it is better to run the SDK as an administrator.